# Create JSON structure based on input variables

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
   "outer_size":2,
   "inner_size":{
      "length_one":2,
      "length_two":1
   }
}
```

I will use this info to create a new JSON file, whose dimensions are determined by `outer_size`, `inner_size`, `length_one` and `length_two`. The structure I want to generate has the following form

```
[
   {
      "a":[
         {
            "a_one":1
         },
         {
            "a_two":2
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "b":[
         {
            "b_one":1
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

This structure contains two "outer" variables `a` and `b` because `outer_size=2`.

`a` contains two "inner" variables `a_one` and `a_two`, while `b` contains one "inner" variable `b_one`. This is because `inner_size` is 2 and 1, respectively.

**Question** Based on a given `outer_size`, `inner_size`, `length_one` and `length_two`, what is the best way to generate a JSON structure with those dimensions? Can/should it be done with **classes**?

Please note the following

1. The value of `outer_size` must always be equal to the number of `length_XX`-specifications (in the above example 2). In case it is 3, we will have to specify `length_three` too.
2. The specific values of `a_one`, `a_ two` etc... can be whatever for this example. Now my main concern is merely to construct the basic structure.
3. I'm using Nlohmann's JSON library for reading the initial JSON file.

Comment: `"outer_size":2` seems unneeded, as it is the number of key of `"outer_size":2`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks. I'd like `outer_size` to be a variable too, so in case where it is 3 we have to specify `length_three` as well

Answer (score 0):

Without using any JSON library, I have been using this code to produce JSON code "manually".

```
fputs("[\n",file);
fputs("\t{\n",file);
fputs("\t\t\"a\":[\n" ,file);
fputs("\t\t     {\n",file);
fprintf(file,\t\t\t\"a_one\": \"%s\",\n",functionReturningJSONValue());
```

Which would print something like that you have asked. I haven't done it fully but I am sure you will understand how it works.
Hoping it helped you a bit.

You can still loop in order to create a certain size of JSON and input values with fprintf.